# Getting data from Go template in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, go, beego

I am new in Angular Js. I managed to receive the data from golang in angular js. But it's giving an output **[object Object]** when used in an alert box. I tried changing the delimiters of golang from **{{ }}** to **<<< >>>**, but the problem was not solved.

Go code: (I am using beego)

```
func (receiver *AdsController) LoadNewCampaignPage()  {
    view := viewmodels.NewCampaignPageViewModel{}
    view.Title = "New Campaign"
    receiver.Data["vm"] = view
    receiver.Layout = "layouts/ads_header.html"
    receiver.TplName = "templates/ads_add_campaign.html"
}
```

Struct **viewmodels.NewCampaignPageViewModel{}**

```
type NewCampaignPageViewModel struct {
    Title           string
    ProfileName     string
    ProfilePicture  string
    UnUsedBoxes     []models.Box
    ErrorMessage    string
}
```

Html

```
<div ng-controller="AddBoxForAdsCtrl">
    <button class="_button _button-3" ng-click="showHiddenForm()">Add Box</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var addBoxForAds = angular.module('addBoxForAds', []);
addBoxForAds.controller('AddBoxForAdsCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
     var title = $http.get('<<<.vm.Title>>>'); //Data from GO; delimiters are changed.
     alert(title);
});
```

What are the mistakes I made here? How can I get the data from golang in angularjs? How to use use the struct element **UnUsedBoxes**(which is an array of struct)?

Comment: do console.log instead of alert then check what is coming in objects

Comment: You need to pass an url endpoint as parameter to  `http.get`.

Comment: @SimoEndre Can you please explain what to do?

Comment: Can you show the response you get when you are trying to access the url route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.get` makes get request to server to fetch json data and you are just passing value straight to js-code. If I figured out you correctly, you need to change your code to

```
var title = '<<<.vm.Title>>>';
```

Or, you can make function in Go like in this dummy example (may look different on beego framework):

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/title", title_handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func title_handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    title := map[string]string{"title": "My Title"}
    // this should work too:
    // title := struct {title string} {"My Title"}

    json_title, _ := json.Marshal(title)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(json_title)
}
```

And in js:

```
var title = $http.get('/title');
```

Comment: That was my first try.. But it turns out to be an error, so js stopped working. That's why I used '$http.get'.

Comment: Is this possible with struct too?